# Make Firefox open an URL or focus the window/tab if already loaded

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line

Is there a way to make Firefox open a new window on a certain URL or raise the tab/window where that URL is already loaded?

I would like to call Firefox with

```
firefox --open-or-focus http://example.com
```

and have Firefox either

- open a new window and load http://example.com if no windows are open on http://example.com,
- raise the existing Firefox tab/window that is already open on http://example.com.

Firefox already have a similar functionality embedded in the location bar (try typing an address which you already have in an open tab), is it exposed to the command line as well?

Answer (score 3):

[Mozilla's documentation for Firefox's command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) doesn't write about any such feature. I tried to check the documentation available on firefox's binary as well and it doesn't do this.

You have switches to open new tabs and new windows but none to get a list of tabs open which you could potentially read off a script.

**Simple answer, can't be done** unless you start reading the Firefox profiles to figure it out. Doesn't seem worth the effort :)

Also, another thing I noticed when running Firefox off command line is that it blocks your terminal to keep the process running (I'm running this off a Mac but it should be the same for Linux). If you do want to CLI Firefox in a linux environment (considering the tags this post has), you might want to [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) it.